# Relation-Triples extraction in R - tm, stringr, perl regex

Tags: r, nlp, relation, text-extraction, tm

In a case of ontology learning from texts, suppose I have two concepts and I'm interested in the relation between them:

```
class <- c(animal.class, dog.class)
individual <- "Snoopy"

animal.class <- c("animal", "animals")
dog.class <- c("dog", "dogs")

sentence1 <- "Snoopy is an animal."
sentence2 <- "Snoopy is a dog."
```

How to extract linguistic context and semantic relations with R in such way that I can collect data frames without having the context/relation ("is a(n)") defined before.

```
data.frame(CLASS1="animal",CLASS2="Snoopy",context="CLASS2 is an CLASS1")
data.frame(CLASS1="dog",CLASS2="Snoopy",context="CLASS2 is a CLASS1")
```

It's easy to extract this kind of thing with other tools like finite state transducer, but I would like to stay in R and I didn't find anything like that for the moment in R.

I imagine some solutions with perl regex and the packages `tm` and `stringr`... are they sufficient?

Comment: It's unclear what would be the data available and what would be the expected outcome. Do you want to deduct classes given some sentences, or generate sentences given classes? Or...?

Comment: Possibly the qdap package of Tyler Rinker could help.

Comment: @DominicComtois : data available are sentences or corpus. NLTK (Python) have a specific function : http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sem/relextract.html

Comment: Maybe @lawyeR's suggestion is a good one, see https://github.com/trinker for details. Otherwise if there exists developed tools in another language such as Python, it can be worth the effort to plunge in that language for the time of this endeavor. In all transparency I must admit I was a big fan or Python in a not-so-distant life, so maybe I'm a little biased here ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after.  This is how I'd approach what I think you're after:

```
sentences <- c(
    "Snoopy is an animal.",
    "Snoopy is a dog.",
    "Snoopy likes chocolate!",
    "Goofy is a dog"
)

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(qdapRegex, dplyr, tidyr)

(out <- rm_default(sentences, pattern = S("@around_", 1, "is a(n*)", 1), extract=TRUE) %>%
    unlist %>%
    sub("\\s+", "<SPLIT>", .) %>%
    data_frame(new = .)  %>% 
    na.omit %>%
    separate(new, c("CLASS2", "context", "CLASS1"), sep = "(<SPLIT>)|( (?=[^ ]+$))") %>%
    mutate(context = sprintf("CLASS 2 %s CLASS 1", context)) %>%
    select(c(1, 3, 2))) 

##   CLASS2 CLASS1               context
## 1 Snoopy animal CLASS 2 is an CLASS 1
## 2 Snoopy    dog  CLASS 2 is a CLASS 1
## 3  Goofy    dog  CLASS 2 is a CLASS 1
```

Then to pull out specific instances of various CLASSes use `filter` on the end of the piping:

```
out %>%
    filter(grepl("[Ss]noopy", CLASS2))

##   CLASS2 CLASS1               context
## 1 Snoopy animal CLASS 2 is an CLASS 1
## 2 Snoopy    dog  CLASS 2 is a CLASS 1

out %>%
    filter(grepl("[Dd]og", CLASS1))

##   CLASS2 CLASS1              context
## 1 Snoopy    dog CLASS 2 is a CLASS 1
## 2  Goofy    dog CLASS 2 is a CLASS 1
```